# css vertically align div while keeping margins

Tags: html, css

I have this html & css, which allows me to center my content inside the container:

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

This works great, but when I reduce the height of the browser window so it becomes shorter than the content, the top part of the content box goes up and out of view. I would like the content box to always have a 20px of top and bottom margins. Is it possible to achieve this with css alone? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### This is how you can do that without much code

https://codepen.io/bhupinderkumarbl/pen/WXQxam

```
       .container{
            height: 100vh; 
            display:flex;
            justify-content:center;
            flex-direction:column;
            text-align:center
      }
    h1{ margin:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give your `.content` a max-height and overflow, so it is possible to scroll inside it:

```
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
}
```